# How do I get the number of a specific place in an int in C++?

Tags: c++

So I have an int that counts upwards.

Let's say we're up to 65,000 already.

I need to get the number in the thousandth place (the 5), to be assigned to another int.

I found the following snippet which is pretty easy but not quite what I need.

> You can use % operator for any number of integers you want to
>   separate. For example 888881%10 will give you 1 and 888881%100 will
>   give you 81...

Thanks!

Comment: hint: how can you use the `%` operator to get something that starts with the `5`?  And then how can you use the `/` operator to extract just the first digit of that?

Comment: There is no answer accepted. Did you found an answer to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need this.

```
int AtPos(int number, int pos)
{
    return ((number > 0 ? number : -number) / (int)pow(10, pos)) % 10;
}
```

If this is that you are looking for, arguments validity check should be added.

---

**EDIT.**

I just noticed, you need to assign different number in specified position. So you need this improvement:

```
int& SetValueAtPos(int& number, int pos, int newValue)
{
    int power = (int)pow(10, pos);
    number -= AtPos(number, pos) * power;
    number += power * newValue;
    return number;
}
```

---

Additionally you can merge those functions and cache value of `pow(10, pos)` so it would be more optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
int a =65432;
int b = ((a%10000)-(a%1000))/1000;
```

here (a%10000) = 5432
and  (a%1000)  = 432
so   (a%10000)-(a%1000) will be 5000
and finally 5000/1000 = 5

or directly you can use

```
int b = (a%10000)/1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Matt suggested in comment is:

```
int num1 = 65000;
int num2 = num%10000;  //num2 is 5000
num2 = num2/1000;

Output: 5
```